# JS инсценировать клик для отлавливания якоря через функцию

Tags: javascript

Все дело в том что с адресной строки якорь ссылки не отлавливаетя с первого раза. чтобы сработал переход нужно 2 раза нажать в адресной строке, тогда якорь отловится. Так же и функция с якорем запускается только со второго раза. И без ловли через адресную строку якоря, функции в рабочем состоянии. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему! Заранее большое спасибо! Успешных дел и всего самого лучшего. )

```js
if (window.location.hash == '#sup') {
  sup();
  window.location = 'super-landing-page.html#sup';
  console.log('sup');
} else if (window.location == '#arbeiten') {
  console.log('arbeiten');
  arbeiten();
} else if (window.location == '#work') {
  console.log('work');
  work();
} else if (window.location == '#nav') {
  nav();
} else if (window.location == '#advantages') {
  advantages();
} else if (window.location == '#warranty') {
  warranty();
} else if (window.location == '#positiveKey') {
  positiveKey();
} else {
  // window.location='/';
  console.log('Nul');
}
```

Рабочий скрипт лендинг на странице https://nasobe.ru/super-landing-page.html /Mеню с якорями в середине. Само меню с якорями отображается только если ширина экрана меньше 900px

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event

Comment: Ссработало! Большое спасибо за помощь! Кому будет интересно обертка: 
window.onhashchange=()=>{ "тут код и функции" };  -ставит прослушку на изменение ссылки

Comment: Вообще-то не ссылки, а той её части, которая после `#`. И так можно с любыми событиями делать `.onclick`, `.onchange` и т.д.